# How can I fix these Trigger Errors? Oracle 11g Express

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

code:

```
create or replace trigger "ARTICULOSCAT_INSERT" AFTER insert on 
"ARTICULOSCAT" for each row BEGIN INSERT INTO
BITACORA (USUARIO,FECHA,TABLA_AFECTADA,ACCION_EFECTUADA,COLUMNAS,VALORES_ANT,VALORES_NUEVOS) 
VALUES(USER,SYSDATE,'ArticulosCat','Insert','I_ID_ARTICULO,V_DESCRIPCION_100,I_ID_UM,F_PRECIO,I_ID_IMPUESO',
CONCAT('I_ID_ARTICULO:  ',:OLD.I_ID_ARTICULO,',','V_DESCRIPCION_100:  ',:OLD.V_DESCRIPCION_100,',','I_ID_UM: ',:OLD.I_ID_UM,',','F_PRECIO: ',:OLD.F_PRECIO,',','I_ID_IMPUESTO: ',:OLD.I_ID_IMPUESTO),
CONCAT('I_ID_ARTICULO:  ',:NEW.I_ID_ARTICULO,',','V_DESCRIPCION_100:  ',:NEW.V_DESCRIPCION_100,',','I_ID_UM: ',:NEW.I_ID_UM,',','F_PRECIO: ',:NEW.F_PRECIO,',','I_ID_IMPUESTO: ',:NEW.I_ID_IMPUESTO) 
END;​
```

> **Error:**
>
> Compilation failed, line 3 (02:17:30) The line numbers associated with
>   compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This
>   only affects the compilation of database triggers. PL/SQL: ORA-00909:
>   invalid number of argumentsCompilation failed, line 2 (02:17:30) The
>   line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the
>   first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database
>   triggers. PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignoredCompilation failed, line 4
>   (02:17:30) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are
>   relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the
>   compilation of database triggers. PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case
>   declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise
>   return select update while with

Comment: It's a typo error - you are missing a closing parenthesis for the values statement. You can see the final concat ending parenthesis, and it is not followed by another to close the `values(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in your use of the `CONCAT` function. As you can see [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions033.htm#SQLRF00619), this only accepts two parameters.

What you should use instead is the concatenation operator `||`, as this can be used to string together many different parts and is, IMO, far easier to read than a series of nested CONCATs!

Therefore your trigger would look something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER articuloscat_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON articuloscat
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO bitacora
    (usuario,
     fecha,
     tabla_afectada,
     accion_efectuada,
     columnas,
     valores_ant,
     valores_nuevos)
  VALUES
    (USER,
     SYSDATE,
     'ArticulosCat',
     'Insert',
     'I_ID_ARTICULO,V_DESCRIPCION_100,I_ID_UM,F_PRECIO,I_ID_IMPUESO',
     'I_ID_ARTICULO:  ' || :old.i_id_articulo || ',' || 'V_DESCRIPCION_100:  ' || :old.v_descripcion_100 || ',' || 'I_ID_UM: ' || :old.i_id_um || ',' || 'F_PRECIO: ' || :old.f_precio || ',' || 'I_ID_IMPUESTO: ' || :old.i_id_impuesto,
     'I_ID_ARTICULO:  ' || :new.i_id_articulo || ',' || 'V_DESCRIPCION_100:  ' || :new.v_descripcion_100 || ',' || 'I_ID_UM: ' || :new.i_id_um || ',' || 'F_PRECIO: ' || :new.f_precio || ',' || 'I_ID_IMPUESTO: ' || :new.i_id_impuesto);
END articuloscat_insert;
/
```

You were also missing a semi-colon (;) at the end of the insert, which I have added for you.